# Why are linked lists not used frequently in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I’ve been working with JavaScript for around 4 years. In all the applications I’ve worked on, I’ve never once seen someone use a linked list. Why is that? Data structures are so prominently featured in most learn-to-program courses. Yet I almost never see them used in the real world.

Comment: They are too low level. You already have the array type, which is mostly implemented in native code and useful in the general case. One benefit of linked lists is quick removal of elements. In javascript its not really worth worrying about.

Comment: This is off–topic here as answers will be almost entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the perfect explanation of this but I think will give you a fair idea about it.

- The scenarios which will make sense to use Linked list on JavaScript
  are very rare. You have been working on JavaScript for 4 years when
  did you feel a need to use linked lists and not JavaScript `Array`
- The main purpose of using linked list is performance improvements,
  when there a is a huge collection of records and frequent changes to
  them linked lists help in optimizing that. But that case may not be
  true for most of the JavaScript applications. Arrays are pretty much
  bale to do that for JavaScript.
- Most of the frameworks rely on array's be it React, Vue etc.
- In case of linked list methods like unshift, etc. are much faster.
  while methods on Arrays, such as push, run considerably faster than
  Linked Lists.
- The use of linked list is justified when you need to make a lot of
  modifications to a huge list — especially when adding or removing
  items somewhere other than the end of the list and such cases are rare in 
  JavaScript/front end.
- Last but not the least JavaScript has great support for Arrays but
  you will have to code your own implementation or use some library
  that provides linked lists implementation.